# Got the error:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte, playsound

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, mp3, python-playsound

I was making a program that plays a song from playsound but I got the error:"UnicodeDecodeError:'t decode byte 0xe3 at position 1: invalid continuation byte" What to do to play the song.

This was my code:

```
from playsound import playsound


playsound('C://Users//hp//Desktop//francisco//non-school work//musica.mp3')
```

This was the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hp/Desktop/francisco/trabalhos que não são da escola/projeto1/ex021.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/francisco/trabalhos que não são da escola/musica.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried to remove double slashes and shows another error:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\francisco\trabalhos que não são da escola\musica.mp3')
input()
```

The error:

```
 File "c:/Users/hp/Desktop/francisco/trabalhos que não são da escola/projeto1/ex021.py", line 3
    playsound('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\francisco\trabalhos que não são da escola\musica.mp3')
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I already solved the problem just doing this:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('musica.mp3')
input()
```

What was the problem???

Comment: Please post the full error message including the traceback

Comment: There double slashes are unnecessary. Have you tried without them?

Comment: If I trie whithout double slashes shows another error

Comment: I already edit the post with the 2 errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the file was written in a different encoding than what the playsound module is expecting.

If you have created the mp3 file yourself, maybe you have not chosen the right encoding.

Otherwise, it might be a bug of the playsound module.

Update:
The error message actually refers to the file path you are providing, not the file itself. As you are working on Windows and paths are build with backslashes, which are a special character in Python strings, you need to use either double backslashes instead of a single backslash as in

```
'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\francisco\\trabalhos que não são da escola\\musica.mp3'
```

or you provide the string as a raw string by putting an "r" before the first quotation mark, like this:

```
r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\francisco\trabalhos que não são da escola\musica.mp3'
```

Update 2: Combining f-string and r-string

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(rf"{r'C:\Users'}").exists()
File "<ipython-input-45-dc9a3746d390>", line 1
Path(rf"{r'C:\Users'}").exists()
             ^
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash


Path(rf"{'C:'}\{'Users'}").exists()
Out[46]: True
Path(fr"{'C:'}\{'Users'}").exists()
Out[47]: True
```

Comment: How could a binary file (mp3) have a different text-encoding?

Comment: I made a download of a mp3 file from web, I didn't created this mp3 file

Comment: I try to use pygame instead and it worked, why with playsound doesn't work?

Comment: @Sören, that is a good point. Yet this error does occur. 
I just realized what the actual problem is and it has not much to do with the file. I will update my answer.

Comment: @FEngineer, what I have to do to use f-strings and an "r" before the first quotation mark?

Comment: This seems to be rather flexible as long as you do not use backslash within the curly braces in the f-string. See my 2nd update of the original answer.